# Reading a string with blank spaces

Tags: c, file, data-structures

I'm trying to read a file using a structure, seems all fine until I face a string with spaces, let me give you an example.

In my file I've got text like this:

Luca 21 Università di Palermo 22.3

I can read all the row, but when I arrive at the third element which is the university, it reads only the "Università" and not the rest.
I've tried using [^\t\n] but then it reads the next information also and I don't want this.
This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct{
    char nome[30];
    int eta;
    char universita[30];
    double media;
}Studente;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    FILE* fp;
    Studente s;
    if((fp=fopen("studenti.txt", "r ")) == NULL){
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }

    char buffer[200];   //tipicamente 200 caratteri stanno su una riga
   // fgets(buffer, 200, fp);  //facciamo una prima lettura
    
    /*while(!feof(fp)){
        sscanf(buffer, " %s %d %s %f", &s.nome, &s.eta, &s.universita, &s.media); //assegnamo il valore della stringa contenuta nel buffer ai tre indirizzi di memoria
        printf("Lo studente si chiama: %s\n", s.nome);
        printf("Ha %d anni\n", s.eta);
        printf("Frequenta %s\n", s.universita);
        printf("Ha una media del %6f\n", s.media);
        fgets(buffer, 200, fp); //continuiamo a leggere
    }*/

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)){
        sscanf(buffer, " %s %d %s %f", s.nome, &s.eta, s.universita, &s.media); //assegnamo il valore della stringa contenuta nel buffer ai tre indirizzi di memoria
        printf("Lo studente chiama: %s\n", s.nome);
        printf("Ha %d anni\n", s.eta);
        printf("Frequenta %s\n", s.universita);
        printf("Ha una media del %lf\n", s.media);
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

The output that I want is:
The name is X
He is y
He goes at z
His score is k

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you, as a human, able to know where the university ends and the score begins? This is first and foremost a data question (what guarantees do you have about the data being stored), and second a programming question.

Comment: I suppose that, if I see a number after the string, this would mean that I've ended the reading of that string and a new line with digits will start @JohnFilleau

Comment: A "string" is a sequence of characters. Digits are characters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- Student name does not include spaces.
- University name may contain spaces but does not include digits.
- Average (media) does not start with a dot, such as `.12`.

Then would you please try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <string.h>
//#include <ctype.h>
#define FILENAME "studenti.txt"

typedef struct {
    char nome[30];
    int eta;
    char universita[30];
    double media;
} Studente;

/*
 * removes trailing spaces of str by modifying the array str
 */
char *trimright(char *str)
{
    char *p;
    for (p = str; *p != '\0'; p++);
    for (--p; p - str >= 0 && (*p == ' ' || *p == '\t') ; p--) {
        *p = '\0';
    }
    return str;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    Studente s;
    char buffer[200];   // tipicamente 200 caratteri stanno su una riga
    int n;              // count the number of elements

    if ((fp = fopen(FILENAME, "r")) == NULL) {
        perror(FILENAME);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) {
        n = sscanf(buffer, "%s %d %[^0-9] %lf", s.nome, &s.eta, s.universita, &s.media);
        if (n == 4) {
            printf("Lo studente chiama: %s\n", s.nome);
            printf("Ha %d anni\n", s.eta);
            printf("Frequenta %s\n", trimright(s.universita));
            printf("Ha una media del %f\n", s.media);
        } else {
            printf("Possible format error with: %s", buffer);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The identifier `%[^0-9]` makes `sscanf` read characters other than digits.
then the parsed string `s.universita` may contain trailing space character(s).
The function `trimright` is applied to trim them. If you don't mind including
trailing space characters, you don't need to use the function.

If you want to allow digits in the university name, please let me know.